# Why is the op-amp able to eliminate negative voltage?

Tags: operational-amplifier, modulation

I have a circuit with the attached waveform. Can someone please explain why the 2nd op-amp (middle) is able to eliminate the negative voltage? By reasoning and analysing the circuit I can see that the 1st op-amp is an inverting amplifier and the last one is an active low-pass filter, but I can't really see how the middle op-amp is able to produce such an output.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks to me like U1 (the middle op-amp) is a differential amplifier (aka voltage subtractor) with a gain of 1. Its inputs are the left end of R3 and the top end of R5.

Comment: "I can see that the 1st op-amp is an inverting amplifier".  Kinda.  D1 is in series with R4, and that is important.  This is not a standard inverting amplifier.  The circuit is called an active rectifier.

Comment: From the scope screen shot I think you need some decoupling capacitors on your op amp power supplies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice D1 and D2.

For a -ve half cycle, D1 doesn't conduct, U1 in+ = 0 (via R4 to the virtual earth), U1 gain is -R7/R3 = -1.

For a positive half cycle, D1 conducts, U1 in+ = V/2 set by R5,R6.
But D2 doesn't conduct, and R2 leads to the virtual earth. So U1 is now a NON-inverting amplifier with gain approx(*) 1 + R7/R3 = 2.

So the gain alternates between -1 and (+2*0.5) according to the input polarity.

(*) Strictly 1 + R7/(R3+R2). See if you can identify a small mismatch between gain at +ve and -ve peaks in simulation, and correct it by e.g. modifying R3. This is probably why R2,R4 impedances are kept relatively low compared with R3 etc.

Answer (score 1):

> the 1st op-amp is an inverting amplifier

Yes, but each semi-cycle uses one of the feedback resistors in series with a diode (only one conducts at each semi-cycle). Here, before connecting to the second stage:

[image]

The opamp compensates for the diode drop (it is briefly in open loop at the zero crossings). It becomes clear that a full-wave rectifier is obtainable (with gain) by subtracting \$V_b - V_a\$

[image]

> why the 2nd op-amp (middle) is able to eliminate the negative voltage?

The second stage implements the difference amplifier (\$V_b - V_a\$), but it loads the input \$V_a\$ when diode **D1** (**D2** in your circuit) is not conducting  (there is also a fixed loading to GND at the other branch). By increasing the resistor values, this becomes almost irrelevant:

[image]

[image]